# $\int_0^x | t| dt = \frac{x|x|}{2}, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove or give a counter example.
$\int_0^x | t| dt = \frac{x|x|}{2}, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

so, if $x < 0 \Rightarrow |t| = -t \Rightarrow\int_0^x (-t) dt = \frac{(-x)x}{2}$
for $x \ge 0 \Rightarrow |t| = t \Rightarrow\int_0^x t dt = \frac{xx}{2}$

but this doesn't seems right .. i think is missing the "proof". or for $\epsilon > 0$ that integral became different of the $\frac{x|x|}{2}$ because of the small difference of upper sums and lower sums .

well, i don't know .. thanks for any help

Comment: The identity is correct, and but I think you should apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. What you are doing now is assuming the result is true.

Comment: @Nameless thanks for your reply. $\int_0^x (-t) dt = \frac{(-x)x}{2}$ i use  the theorem of calculus.. well, thats how i get $\frac{(-x)x}{2}$. but, to finish with $\frac{x|x|}{2}$ from the both equations, for me, seems that is missing something. Maybe is that what your are saying ..

Comment: Oh, I thought you just plugged in the $-$ on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

1. $\forall x>0$ , $\displaystyle \int_{0}^x |t|$ $\mathrm{d}t=\displaystyle \int_{0}^x t$ $\mathrm{d}t=\dfrac{x^2}{2}$
2. $\forall x<0$ , $\displaystyle \int_{0}^x |t|$ $\mathrm{d}t=-\displaystyle \int_{x}^0 (-t)$ $\mathrm{d}t=-\dfrac{x^2}{2}$
3. $x=0$ $\implies$  $\displaystyle \int_{0}^x |t|$ $\mathrm{d}t=0$

$\therefore$ $\displaystyle \int_{0}^x |t|$ $\mathrm{d}t=\dfrac{x|x|}{2}$